# Is the latest Canon Pixma TS5350 firmware update erroneous?

Tags: firmware, canon-pixma

A client of mine has this printer. He installed a firmware update a week ago using the device's screen. Since then it's not possible to use the printer. The printer shows error 6800 and as description for this error it says there is a foreign object inside. It's not possible to remove the error message. It's not possible to enter the settings to perform a factory reset. We didn't find any foreign object inside. Also holding the power button and then pressing stop 5 times (during startup to perform a factory reset) did not work.

I cannot verify if it's true what my client said so I am asking if anyone has this printer and installed a firmware update in February 2023 and if the device still worked after that?

Comment: Where did he get the update from?

Comment: @harrymc As written in the question he installed it using the device's screen. So it was an official Canon update.

Comment: Still seems fishy.